# R: Fastest way to compare i element of a vector with all the previous ones

Tags: r, loops, vector, vectorization

I have around 1200 dataframes of approximately 25000 values each one.

This dataframes contain basically an incremental time series that some times have errors in the measurements and drops to 0 before it goes to the right value again (case 1) or drops to 0 but it does not correct automatically (case 2).

Case1 example:

[image]

Case2 example:

[image]

I would like to retag the points that are less than the previous values. Basically for every value i I want to compare value i with all of the the previous ones j (being j=length(vector)-i)I tried to do as follows:

`x <- c(10,11,12,13,14,1,7,8,14,16,19,22)
y <- x
sapply(x,function(z){z<y})`

Getting the following:

```
       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
 [1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [3,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [4,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [5,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [7,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [8,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [9,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[10,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[11,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[12,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

However I am not able to extract a pattern that I can use to filter this data out.

Has someone tried this before?

Comment: What is your goal? What do you expect as a result? So each data frame has only one column?

Comment: The `diff` function returns the successive difference between consequtive values. So you can just try `diff(y) < 0` or `which(diff(y)<0)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the idea is that the series is supposed to be non-decreasing then

```
ok <- cummax(x) == x
```

is TRUE for the good points and

```
x[ok]
```

is just the good points or

```
cummax(x)
```

is the good points with the bad points replaced with the maximum so far.

Comment: Works like charm and really fast. Thank you!